# How to Run WireShark Commands in command line through C#

Tags: c#, cmd, wireshark, tshark

I want to convert .pcapng files to .csv files using the below commands:

```
     > cd C:\Program Files\Wireshark
     > tshark -r output.pcapng -T fields -e frame.number -e eth.src -e eth.dst -e frame.len -e frame.time -e frame.time_relative -e data -E header=y -E separator=, > output.csv
```

In C#, I used the following code.

```
        string command = @"cd C:\Program Files\Wireshark & tshark -r output.pcapng -T fields -e frame.number -e eth.src -e eth.dst -e frame.len -e frame.time -e frame.time_relative -e data -E header=y -E separator=, > output.csv";
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = command;
        startInfo.Verb = "runas";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

This doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: If it's not working you should be getting some sort of error message or other indication that it is not working.  You should state that in your question.

Comment: Why are you starting a shell (cmd.exe) when all you want to do is run wireshark?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No.. I am not getting any error. Within a millisecond, a window opens and closes after it executes the last line, that is, WaitForExit.

Comment: @Neil I want to convert .pcapng into csv files with filters and this was the command to do that.

Comment: You're attempting to launch tshark from within a shell, which makes getting the arguments correct a lot trickier.  Since I'm guessing you're only doing that to convince tshark to write to a file, consider adding the `-w output.csv` argument to the tshark command.  Then you might not need the shell at all.

Comment: I think what @Neil and @ Gus wer getting as was why are you starting cmd.exe at all?  Why not just start tshark directly?

Answer (score 0):

From `cmd /?`:

```
Starts a new instance of the Windows command interpreter

CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
    [[/S] [/C | /K] string]

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
<snip>
```

Try adding the `/C` to the start of your command string:

```
 string command = @"/C cd C:\ProgramFiles\Wireshark & tshark -r output.pcapng -T fields -e frame.number -e eth.src -e eth.dst -e frame.len -e frame.time -e frame.time_relative -e data -E header=y -E separator=, > output.csv";
```

Update:

The command below works for me. And the number of double quote characters is not a typo. It's 4 at the start of the tshark program path and 3 at the end.

`cmd /k """"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark""" -r output.pcapng -T fields -e frame.number -e eth.src -e eth.dst -e frame.len -e frame.time -e frame.time_relative -e data -E header=y -E separator=, > output.csv"`

Comment: Tried adding "/C" at the beginning. still no luck

Comment: Try /K instead of /C then. It will leave the cmd window open and display any error message.

Comment: After replacing by K, I am getting this error - 'tshark' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Why multiple double quotes? Is this a string to be given as input?

Comment: I get erro - 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I used the below command:
             cmd /K "C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark" -r "D:\FilesToConvert\SampleFile.pcapng" -T fields -e frame.number -e eth.src -e eth.dst -e frame.len -e frame.time -e frame.time_relative -e data -E header=y -E separator=, > "D:\FilesToConvert\output.csv"

Answer (score 0):

Check that path:

`string command = @"cd C:\ProgramFiles\Wireshark & tshark -r output.pcapng -T fields -e frame.number -e eth.src -e eth.dst -e frame.len -e frame.time -e frame.time_relative -e data -E header=y -E separator=, > output.csv";`

On my machine, `Program Files` has a space between the two words, and `Wireshark & tshark` is suspicious too.  Ampersand (especially when using shells) is interpreted differently.

Comment: Yes. The space between Program and Files was one mistake. After correcting that, I am getting this error - 'tshark' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Is `tshark` in the `Wireshark` folder?  if so, you need to replace that ampersand with a slash   `C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark`.